# Metal price web site with silver animal on it?

Tags: trading, online-tools, commodities, websites, metals

I remember there is (or was) a web site about mining and metals and had trading prices for all the metals, including base metals.

The site had a what looked a steel bear or lion on it as a symbol.

Does anyone know which site this was/is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the site you are referring to is http://www.metalprices.com/
It contains prices and charts for all metals and metal indexes.

Comment: Yes, that's right. Apparently they changed their website so they no longer have the metallic bear on it.

Comment: Yes that's right, it did until recently. They have modernised their site somewhat. Their old one can still be seen at http://www.metalprices.com/index.asp